# How to select duplicate IDs with different values?

Tags: database, excel, stata

I am looking at a dataset in Stata that has many duplicate ID values (each representing a single person) but each instance of an ID can have one of two values. For example,

```
PersonID | Place
------------------------
1        | New York
1        | New York
1        | Berlin
2        | Chicago
2        | Chicago
3        | Berlin
3        | Chicago
```

I want to select **only** ID's 1 and 2 because they have mixed values and **ignore** ID 3, but still treat 1 and 2 as single persons.

I would appreciate tips on how to do this in either Stata or Excel. I don't have access to SQL.

**Edit**

I changed my original pseudo chart to better reflect my data.

Here is the code that I have already tried:

```
sort PersonID Place
by PersonID(Place), sort: gen mix=Place[1] != Place[_n]
count PersonID Place if mix
```

and this did not work. It gave me the following error after line 2:

```
factor variables and time-series operators not allowed
```

To be more clear, what I want is the count of PersonID's that have mixed place values.

Comment: There are many ways to do this using VBA in Excel. I would start with a loop within a loop that tests if there are any other ID's with the same number and if they have the same value or build a list of ID's and use an autofilter and test if all of the values are the same for each ID.

Comment: What have you tried ? (I'm particularly interested in Stata code but I assume other software users would like to know too.)

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I have tried doing `sort ID by BookingID: gen duplicate=_n` and then using `count if duplicate==1 & response==1 & response==0`, where 1 and 0 are y and n respectively... and pretty much every combination of that.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I'm thinking that I should identify which booking ID's have both answers and THEN count the duplicates but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Better to edit your question to show code. Experienced Stata users can just about read it, but it would be clearer for everyone to display it properly.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for the advice I should get better at writing pseudo code because I can't post my actual code on the internet.

Comment: You just showed code in your comment so you can post code just like anyone else. The point was that it would have been better in the question where you can add newlines (and better formatting).

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Try posting an example of how you want your final database to look like and a description. Also, in your attempted code (previous comment), you have have four variables, whereas in your post you show two. The inconsistencies in the naming convention and quantities can be confusing for those trying to help. Instead of adding important information in comments, go ahead and _edit_ your original post.

Comment: `bysort PersonID (Place): gen mix = Place[1] != Place[_N]` Note in particular that it must be `_N` not `_n`.

Comment: Note also that your counting counts observations, not identifiers.

Comment: It should be `by PersonID (Place)`, not `by PersonID(Place)`. Note the blank. @Nick already pointed out other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already documented as an FAQ: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/listing-observations-in-group/ from which

```
bysort id (value) : gen wanted = value[1] == "n" & value[_N] == "y"
```

is a solution for `value` as a string variable. From what you say

```
bysort id (value) : gen wanted = value[1] != value[_N]
```

is a more general solution. In both examples, the variable `wanted` will be 1 for wanted IDs and 0 otherwise.

Missing values would complicate this.

Comment: I'm sorry I thought it worked but I was using the wrong variable as the value. When I inserted the correct value, it gave me this error: `factor variables and time-series operators not allowed`

Comment: I updated my original question to be more clear. I don't know why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Extended generate (aka `egen`, and its user-written companion of additional functions `egenmore`) are very handy for tasks such as these:

```
ssc install egenmore    
bys PersonID: egen nvals=nvals(Place)
edit if nvals >1
```

I am not sure what "still treat 1 and 2 as single persons" means, but this should get you started.